# Параметризация JSON в LoadRunner

Tags: java, json

У меня есть скрипт в LoadRunner который отправлет сообщение в кафку. Сообщение реализовано как строка JSON. Там есть параметр isActive который гененрируется выше в скрипте, я хочу его подставить в это сообщение, но когда подставляю у меня возникает ошибка, если убрать параметр то сообщение отправляется без проблем. Пробовала как обычный параметр в LR через фигурные скобки, без и с добавлением "", через lr_save_param. Ниже прикладываю скрин ошибок.
Пример соообщения:

```
    String jsonMessage1 = "{"+                    
    "    \"Account\": {"+                  
    "     \"OpeningDate\": \"2015-03-24\","+       
    "     \"ClosingDate\": \"2022-10-08\","+          
    "     \"Status\": \"1\"," +            
    "     \"IsActive\": "{IsActive}","+
    "     \"Type\": 16"     
    "   }"+                             
    "}";
```

[image: Ошибки]

Подскажите, как можно правильно это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Ну, тут две ошибки вижу, во-первых, переменные надо вставлять с конвертацией в String при помощи lr_eval_string, во-вторых, кавычки возле переменной тоже надо экранировать, они часть json.
Попробуй заменить

```
"{IsActive}","
```

на

```
" + "\"" + lr_eval_string("{IsActive}") + "\","
```

Comment: Заменила как вы сказали, осталась одна ошибка, что нужна ; Которая самая первая на скрине

Comment: В строчке "     \"Type\": 16" надо + в конце дописать, а то стринг обрывается, получается

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помошь, я немного исправила свой код благодаря вашему совету. Я переписала параметр isActive сразу, чтобы он генерировался в string и подставила  без кавычек в JSON, вот что получилось:

```
"    \"IsActive\": \"" + IsActive + "\"," +
```